# What is the difference between "gift" and "present"?

Tags: word-choice, differences, nouns, synonyms

What is the difference between *gift* and *present*?

Comment: A gift is a present that no one wants.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One difference is that we use *birthday gift* or *birthday present* but we only use *free gift* and not *free present*.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the origin of the word. While a gift is simply given, a present is presented.

Comment: -1 This claim that *"**present** is more special than **gift**"* is complete nonsense. I'm not convinced it's meaningful to "rank" these words, but *the gift of life* is probably more "special" than any present you'll ever receive.

Comment: Before it was edited, the answer had the following description: *They are both free, but present is more special than gift and suggests a nontrivial relationship between the giver and the receiver.* Which I kind of liked, especially the reference to "non-trivial relationship", because it's true. Shops, beauticians, perfumeries give away free samples, which are often called "gifts".

Comment: In my understanding they are distinct. A gift is something someone wants you to have, but a present has the additional property that the giver has some idea that it is wanted by the receiver.

Comment: @JoshuaOlson Why would someone give you something that he/she doesn't think that you want?

Comment: Not that they wouldn’t want it, just they haven’t expressed a desire for it. Like giving them a book that from an author they don’t know but you think they’d like.

Answer (score 10):

In many contexts, there is not much difference. I'd say "present" is mostly used in a practical context, when you hand someone a present on his birthday; "gift" is rather used in an abstract or formal context, as in the gift of telepathy [by supernatural powers], or a gift of land to the church. But this distinction is not at all strict; in many practical situations, they are used interchangeably. I think "present" is the more limited word. When it is used in a formal context, it is often with mild irony: "the Duchy of Burgundy was a handsome present for Maximilian to receive from a potential bride, so the Habsburgs did not need much time to decide on the target of their bribes".

Answer (score 1):

A radio show titled "[Says You!](http://www.saysyou.net/)" had a piece on "what's the difference?"
The answer to gift vs present was that one gives a present in person, but sends a gift. The show itself seems well researched, with the occasional listener letter sent in and read as a correction.

Answer (score -2):

I once heard that a present was something the giver chose because it was something he/she wanted the person they were *presenting* it to to have; while a gift was something that was given because it was something that the giftee has expressed a desire to have.

Comment: And how does this distinction fit with the usage of, say, "the gift of healing" or any other similar expression?

Comment: This answer doesn't account for the definition of *present* used in the question.

Answer (score -4):

They are both free, but *present* is more official than *gift*.

Comment: Really?  I would tend to say the opposite, and even that wouldn't be a foolproof or complete delineation between the two.